# How to secure Kibana with oss distrubtion

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-7

I tried to installed x-pack on Kibana but i got this error:

```
xxx@debian:x/x/bin$ sudo elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
ERROR: X-Pack is not available with the oss distribution; to use X-Pack features use the default distribution
```

There is another way to use x-pack with oss distribution. otherwise there is another free security tool to remplace it ?

Answer (score -1):

The "default" distribution of Kibana and Elasticsearch have security baked in: see [the announcement blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free). X-Pack ceased to exist with v6.3.

So, just download regular [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) and [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) and off you go.

Comment: For the sake of transparency: It is free to use and source available, but not OSS according to the OSI definition; [license details](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt).

Comment: Thanks mike , i was trying to install an alternative of x-pack on my oss distribution but still not resolved ( version 7.2.1 not available witj ReadonlyRest , permission issue with search-guard)